# VS Code terminal appearing on the side and not the bottom

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

My VS Code Terminal/Problems/Output/Debug is appearing on the side like this - [image]

However, I want it to appear at the bottom like this - [image]

How do I make it appear at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right Click on Terminal    [Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SErKK.png)
- Click on Move Panel To Bottom [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkZkK.png)
- Then you can see your terminal at bottom

Answer (score 2):

## HOW TO CHANGE THE POSITION OF THE VSCODE TERMINAL

1. Right Click on the Terminal Toolbar (If you do not do right click in the terminal, it will not work)
2. Select the option Move panel to bottom

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make terminal appear at bottom as default, do following:

1. Open settings [<kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>]
2. Type *terminal default location*
3. Find *Terminal>Integrated>Default Location* and change value to **view**